# Getting the client IP in rails when using cloudflare

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a bit confusing for me.
Per the document, if someone is accessing to cloudflare through a proxy, cloudflare will in turn set a X-Forwarded-For header in this order: `X-Forwarded-For: client-ip, proxy-ip`

But when I invoke `request.ip` in rails, it will return `proxy-ip` instead of `client-ip`.

So why didn't rails return `client-ip`? Isn't it inconsistent to the industrial spec (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)?

**Edit:**

This is how I quickly test how Rails return proxy-ip

```
command
============================
curl -H "X-Forwarded-For: 74.125.130.100, 206.190.36.45" http://localhost:3000/

index.html
============================
request.ip: <%= request.ip %>
request.remote_ip: <%= request.remote_ip %
```

I expect it to be 74.125.130.100 but it always returns 206.190.36.45

Answer (score 0):

An expert I know has pointed out this: http://blog.gingerlime.com/2012/rails-ip-spoofing-vulnerabilities-and-protection/

Rails return the right most ip in the chain that can't be trusted. This is to deal with IP spoofing.